# User Submitted Posts using Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, posts

I am trying to build an application which it will contain an admin dashboard where the admin will be able to CRUD Posts but also he will be able just to see User Submitted Posts.
On the other hand the guest will be able to just see the Posts, but he will be able to Create User Submitted Posts.

Until now I have managed to get the Posts functionality working, but not for the User Submitted Posts.

My Controller:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Usp;

class AdminUserPostsController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $userposts = Usp::orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(10);
        return view('admin.userposts.archive')->withUsp($userposts);
    }

    public function show($id)
    {
        $userpost = Usp::find($id);
        return view('admin.userposts.show')->withUsp($userpost);
    }
}
```

My Model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Usp extends Model
{
    //
}
```

My Archive View

```
@extends('admin')
@section('dashboard-content')
<div class="col-md-8 offset-md-2">
    <h1>Posts Archive</h1>
    <hr>
</div>
@foreach ($userposts as $userpost)
<div class="col-md-6 offset-md-2">
<h3>Title: {{ $userpost->title }}</h3>
<hr>
</div>
@endforeach
@endsection
```

and My Routes(for the specific controller)

```
Route::get('/admin/userposts', 'AdminUserPostsController@index')->name('admin.userposts.archive');
Route::get('/admin/userposts/{id}', 'AdminUserPostsController@show')->name('admin.userposts.show');
```

I am getting the error that userposts variable is not defined, although I define it in my Controller. Anyone that can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should "transmit" your variables to your view. There are several ways to do this, but I'd say the most common is to use the "with compact". In your case, you should change this

```
return view('admin.userposts.archive')->withUsp($userposts);
```

To this

```
return view('admin.userposts.archive')->with(compact('userposts'));
```

**How does it work :**

```
compact("varname", [...])
```

returns an array with the keys being the variable name and the values being the variable values

And the with just transmits all the array to the view

PS :

```
compact('userposts')
```

Is exactly the same as this

```
['userposts' => $userposts]
```

Comment: Thank you so much all of you! Also thanks for the explanation. What about my store function though? When i have to redirect with this code `return redirect()->route('admin.userposts.show', $userpost->id);` I tried to make it `return redirect()->route('admin.userposts.show', compact('userpost', 'id'));` but it doesnt work :(

Comment: The route function does't quite work the same way, for simple things like showing a post you can either pass the value directly like you did with  `$userpost->id`, or you can go for the full object and the framework will decide which value it takes (the id by default) (i.e. just give him `$userpost`). If you wanna change the column, you can change the [implicit binding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing#implicit-binding) column. You only need to pass an array when you have several parameters, the keys being the name of the parameter.

Comment: Furthermore, just to explain `compact('userpost', 'id')`, this would mean that you actually have two variables, one being `$userpost` and the other being `$id`. If you had them both defined, it would return `['userpost' => $userpost, 'id' => $id]`

Comment: This explains much, now i think i can work it out while passing variables in my views with compact. I think now the only problem I have at the moment is that I cant store the userposts since it returns null after i am trying to do `$userpost = new Usp; $userpost->title = $request->title; $userpost->body = $request->body; $userpost->save();` Do i have to use compact in this case aswell ?

Comment: As this is a complete other question, I think that you should make it a separate topic and I'll be happy to answer you over there

Comment: I posted a new thread since this is completed! I hope someone else who is having the same problem will get informed with this! Thank you so much again!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `userposts` variable, do this:

```
return view('admin.userposts.archive', compact('userposts');
```

Or this:

```
return view('admin.userposts.archive', ['userposts' => $userposts]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
return view('admin.userposts.show')->withUsp($userpost);
```

to

```
return view('admin.userposts.show', array('userpost' => $userpost));
```

and try again. You can get `$userpost` on blade view like:

`{{ $userpost }}`

If it is an array, use `foreach()` to get all of its elements.