# User Submitted Posts Store function using Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, routes, posts

So in addition to my prior topic (thank you guys for helping) [routes with compact](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43455324/user-submitted-posts-using-laravel)

I am now facing troubles with my store function, I am getting the error : "Trying to get property of non-object.

This is my store function in my Controller

```
    public function store(Request $request)
{
    // validate the data
    $this->validate($request, array(
            'title' => 'required|max:255',
            'body'  => 'required'
        ));
    // store in the database
    $userpost = new Usp;
    $userpost->title = $request->title;
    $userpost->body = $request->body;
    $userpost->save();
    Session::flash('success', 'The blog post was successfully saved!');
    return redirect()->route('admin.userposts.show', $userpost->id);
}
```

This is the view to create userpost(to make it more clear, p.s. the same form with different route ofcourse, works for my simple posts but not for my user submitted posts)

```
@extends('index')
@section('index-stylesheets')

    {!! Html::style('css/parsley.css') !!}

@endsection
@section('content')
            <h1>Create New User Post</h1>
            <hr>

            {!! Form::open(array('route' => 'admin.userposts.store', 'data-parsley-validate' => '')) !!}
                {{ Form::label('title', 'Title:') }}
                {{ Form::text('title', null, array('class' => 'form-control', 'required' => '', 'maxlength' => '255')) }}

                {{ Form::label('body', "Post Body:") }}
                {{ Form::textarea('body', null, array('class' => 'form-control', 'required' => '')) }}

                {{ Form::submit('Create Post', array('class' => 'btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block', 'style' => 'margin-top: 20px;')) }}
            {!! Form::close() !!}
@endsection

@section('index-scripts')

    {!! Html::script('js/parsley.min.js') !!}

@endsection
```

Method of showing the post:

```
    public function show($id)
{
    $userpost = Usp::find($id);
    return view('admin.userposts.show', compact('userpost'));
}
```

Comment: `['userpost' => $userpost, 'id' => $id]` what is this for???? plz specify which line of the code giving you `Trying to get property of non-object.`

Comment: my bad i was trying something out and i forgot to delete it, but it still doesnt work. I ll update the post. I wish I knew wich line of code gave me this error :( It would be easier for me to look it out aswell. I have exactly the same function in my Posts store function and it is working, but not on user submitted Posts. I am getting the error when I am trying to create the post. The form isnt even showing

Comment: yeah which line of code saying trying to get ..........error msg?

Comment: do you have `$request->title and $request->body`???? passed values as title and body to controller ?

Comment: Can you give us the line of the error please ?

Comment: ErrorException in 0f0374ae4bf12eeb0ed7d126372e90359dc43c0e.php line 2:
Trying to get property of non-object (View: E:\XXXX\resources\views\admin\userposts\show.blade.php)

Comment: Are you sure that the error is in the store function ? Because there is no view ? I think that the error might be _after_ the redirection

Comment: Yes my view seems correct and simple for the purpose of this project (the show view), the create view is on the topic! `@extends('index')
@section('content')
<h1>{{ $userpost->title }}</h1>
<p class="lead">{{ $userpost->body }}</p>
@endsection`

Comment: Can you post the method that you use to show the post ? (Post it in the post, it's better for code formatting)

Comment: if you use `dd($userpost);` just before the return, what does it show ?

Comment: null! I guess the store process is not processed so I have no post to show, so its null. Thats why i jumped into the conclusion it is in the store function

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141924/discussion-between-alex-van-vliet-and-elias-l).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the fact is that the problem was not the store method but the routes.

```
Route::get('/userposts/{id}', 'UserPostsController@show')->name('admin.userposts.show'); 
Route::get('/userposts/create', 'UserPostsController@create')->name('admin.userposts.create'); 
Route::post('/userposts/store', 'UserPostsController@store')->name('admin.userposts.store');
```

When registering the routes in that order, when laravel will iterate over your routes, it will first encounter the show one, and it will therefore take "create" as the id. Therefore, it will go into the show method and it won't find any post that matches, the post being null, you get the error.

So, there are two ways of fixing this.

The first one (the easiest, works in all cases, maybe not the best) is to put the create route before the show route.

The second one, the best in my opinion, is to add a [condition](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing#parameters-regular-expression-constraints) to the id (doesn't work in the case of a slug). As the ids are only integers, you get :

```
Route::get('/userposts/{id}', 'UserPostsController@show')->name('admin.userposts.show')->where('id', '[0-9]+');
```

Therefore, create won't match the regular expression and it won't go in the show method.

---

For "resource creations" (storing in database), I wouldn't use a "field-by-field" method.

Instead, I'd do something like this :

```
$userpost = Usp::create($request->only('title', 'body'));
```

I feel this is more talkative.

But, it won't work, laravel protects* us against such things. To make it work, you have two options.

1. (The best option in my opinion)
   In your model, add a protected variable called $fillable with all your columns that you allow to mass assign*. In this case you would put :

   `protected $fillable = ['name'];`
2. (The option if you are sure of what are you doing)
   In your model, you can say, hey, I know what I'm doing here, just let me do my stuff without guarding me. In this case you would put :

   `protected $guarded = [];`

Notes :

1. `$request->only('field1', ...)` gives you an array of the fields that you want with the fields name as keys, in this case it gives you `['field1' => $request->field1]`. In your case it will give you `['title' => $request->title, 'body' => $request->body]`.
2. Mass assignment is when you give an array to the model and it puts all attributes to the fields of the array. More informations here https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#mass-assignment
3. When I mean laravel protects us against those things, it does't really protect us because it isn't a bad practice (instead, I find it more readable), but because it does allow you to make mistakes (for exemple, setting fields that don't exist).

Comment: That mistake is one of the most annoying I have ever witnessed! Thanks a lot for your time Alex and Jesus Christ guys, dont be a slacker like me, follow the principles!